# Как реализовать раскрытие блока как на сайте?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, materialize-css

Точнее с помощью чего лучше, ну или может у кого-то есть пример?

https://themes.materializecss.com/pages/blog#overhead

Comment: У данного CSS-фреймворка есть такой функционал, почитай внимательно доки. А в целом глянь на [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) и 
[`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

Comment: я что то похожее видел вот здесь : https://tympanus.net/Development/CardExpansion/